# How i convert this href link to JSTL with param

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have this problem when trying to change my code in JSP page to JSTL code. The link I got so far doesn't request to my desired JSP page. Please help me resolve this.

Source code:

```
<a href="showlist?action=detail&bookid=${book.bookid}"/>Detail</a>
```

JSTL code:

```
<c:url value="showlist?action=detail" var="myid">
                    <c:param name="bookid" value="${book.bookid}"/>                     
                </c:url>
                <a href="${myid}">Detail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name should be id as before

```
<c:url value="/showlist" var="myid">
  <c:param name="action" value="detail"/>
  <c:param name="id" value="${book.bookid}"/>  
</c:url>
<a href="${myid}">Detail</a>
```

Comment: I have modified it since my link should be like "/showlist?action=detail&bookid=?". Is different if action must go before bookid ?